# Pass all but the first 2 args of a function to another function

Tags: java, c, jit, ffi, calling-convention

I am planning to write a Java FFI library that will use [DynASM](http://luajit.org/dynasm.html) to generate the FFI trampolines at runtime, instead of performing interpreted calls via libffi.

At least initially, I do not plan on supporting passing/returning composite types by value.  C data structures will be created in Java via direct `ByteBuffer`s. Pointers will be obtained and dereferenced via `sun.misc.Unsafe` and represented as Java `long` values.

A JNI call works as follows:

```c
JNIEXPORT t JNICALL my_c_func(JNIEnv *env, jobject *self, jlong arg);
```

The problem is that there are two unwanted arguments.  I would like to write a trampoline that removes these two arguments and then calls the actual function.  On Windows systems, it needs to translate from `stdcall` (used by JNI on Windows) to either `stdcall`, `cdecl`, or `thiscall`.  Also, DynASM does not support dynamic register allocation.

The question is actually quite simple: How do I (in assembly) pass all but the first two arguments of a function to another function?  In C, I would generate a function as follows:

```c
jlong my_function(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jlong val) {
   return called_function(val);
}
```

I am trying to do this in assembly.  `objc_msgsend` does this for Objective-C programs, but I know of no implementations under permissive licenses.

Comment: What, specifically, is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer two different things, because I am not sure what are you really asking, I don't know if you are asking about:

- Two extra arguments in JNI function to be called from Java code, or
- Two extra arguments in JNI function to be called from C/C++ code.

So I will give you two answer:

### Supposing Java call

I think you believe that `JNIEnv *env, jobject *self` are two unwanted parameters, but they are needed. This parameters are transparent for you since they are managed by JNI.

Let me explain. From Java, you want to invoke a native function, for example:

```
private static native void myFunc(String param1);
```

In order to create a bridge between Java and native C/C++ code, you need to call a native funtcion whose signature will be

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MyClass_myFunc(JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring);
```

As you can see, there are two parameters `JNIEnv *` and `jclass` that are managed from JNI, but your native function only has a `String` param which is mapped to the third `jstring` JNI native call.

### Supposing C/C++ call

If you are trying to invoke this function from another part of a C/C++ code, then you are wrong, because you can't. This function has to be called from JNI, in order to properly pass reference to JNI Environment and to provide self reference to calling object.

If you want to do that, then you will have to create another function, independent of JNI that can be called from the JNI function and from other C/C++ function.

This way you decouple the logic from the view, considering the JNI call a view that can access the logic.

Hope it helps.